# Datepicker Value change windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I navigated to a page where I want to be able to see the date i got from the Database and to edit that date if it is needed. When I change the date, it always go back to the date that was set by the database previously. How do I solve this. Below are my code:

```
private void dateData_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dateData.Value = DateTime.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["Date"]);
    }

private void dateData_ValueChanged(object sender, DateTimeValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dateData.Value = (DateTime)dateData.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think the loaded event is getting called every time you are changing the date and you are assigning the date you are getting from your querystring parameters. So try something like this  And check if it works

```
    private void dateData_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      if(NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Date"))
       {
        dateData.Value = DateTime.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["Date"]);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("Date");
       }
    }
```